# How to point the iterating element in Xpaths in loop in Python

Tags: python-2.7, xpath

I have elements like the following:

```
<div>
<h4> Introduction </h4>
<p> Some text relatted to introduction </p>
<h4> Abstract </h4>
<p> Abstract text </h4>
<h4> reports </h4>
<p> report 1 details </p>
<p> report 2 details </p>
<p> report 3 details </p>
<h4> Conclusion </h4>
<p> Conclusion text </p></div>
```

I have to extract the following information in this format.

`[
{title: 'introduction', 'text': ['Some text relatted to introduction']}, {'title': 'Abstract', 'text': ['Abstract text']}, {'title': 'reports', 'text': ['report 1 details', 'report 2 details', 'report 3 details']}, {'title': 'Conclusion', 'text': ['Conclusion text']}]

- We can iterate on `<h4>` and select the following `<p>` tags. But how to write condition to select the p tags in between two immediate `<h4>` tags?

Please help me in solving the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions are encouraged to provide a [Minimum Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), try to [improve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) yours.

Answer (score 0):

I do not want to give a complete (copy&pastable) Python answer since the question is so sparse. However, I can give some hints:

You can get the heads using XPath using the :nth-child() / [] syntax, eg.

```
//h4[1]
```

to get the 1st `h4` = Introduction, `//h4[2]` the 2nd, etc.
Then, you can select the siblings in a similar fashion, e.g.

```
//h4[3]/following-sibling::p[1]
//h4[3]/following-sibling::p[2]
//h4[3]/following-sibling::p[3]
```

To get the three reports pieces, or `//h4[2]/following-sibling::p[1]` to get the Abstract text.

I suggest taking a look at the [2.7 XML API](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.parse(filename)
result = ''

for elem in root.findall('//h4[2]/following-sibling::p[1]'):
   result = elem.text
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for the response. I have to add another point here. We can have multiple paragraphs to explain about a heading. We should get all the paragraphs related to a heading. According to your answer, we will get only the first paragraph. If you observe my question I have given an example. In the example, please observe the third **<h4>**. For that the result should be **{'title': 'reports', 'text': ['report 1 details', 'report 2 details', 'report 3 details']}**. But we get **{'title': 'reports', 'text': ['report 1 details']}**.

Comment: @silpa As stated, this does not attempt to give a copy & pasteable answer. However, if you have followed my samples you may have noticed: `//h4[3]/following-sibling::p[1]
//h4[3]/following-sibling::p[2]`
//h4[3]/following-sibling::p[3] allows you to do get the three report text blocks. This should be sufficient if your general text structure is as as shown in the OP.